# vc++ undeclared identifier, although its declared

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Im getting a undeclared identifier for 'm_colorGrid' in tetrisdoc.h header file, although its declared:

See the code snippet below:

```
// TetrisDoc.h : interface of the CTetrisDoc class
//


#pragma once
#include "Figure.h"

typedef CList<int> IntList; 
const int FIGURE_ARRAY_SIZE = 7; 
class CTetrisDoc : public CDocument
{
protected: // create from serialization only
    CTetrisDoc();
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CTetrisDoc)
public:
    virtual ~CTetrisDoc();


private:
    ColorGrid m_colorGrid;
    Figure m_activeFigure, m_nextFigure;
    int m_iScore;
    IntList m_scoreList;
    const CRect NEXT_AREA, SCORE_AREA;
    static Figure m_figureArray[FIGURE_ARRAY_SIZE];

// Operations
public:
    void SaveScoreList();
    virtual void Serialize(CArchive& archive);
    int GetScore() const { return m_iScore; }
    const IntList* GetScoreList() { return &m_scoreList; }
    const ColorGrid* GetGrid() 
    { 
        ColorGrid* pm_colorGrid = &m_colorGrid;
        return pm_colorGrid;
    }
    const Figure& GetActiveFigure() { return m_activeFigure; }
    const Figure& GetNextFigure() { return m_nextFigure; }
    void LeftArrowKey(); 
    void RightArroyKey(); 
    void UpArrowKey(); 
    void DownArrowKey();
    BOOL Timer(); 
    void SpaceKey(); 
    enum COLOR {RED=0,BROWN=1,TURQUOISE=2,GREEN=3,BLUE=4,PURPLE=5,YELLOW=6};
    enum ORIENTATION { NORTH = 0, SOUTH = 1,  EAST = 2, WEST = 3 };


// Overrides
public:
    virtual BOOL OnNewDocument();
#ifdef SHARED_HANDLERS
    virtual void InitializeSearchContent();
    virtual void OnDrawThumbnail(CDC& dc, LPRECT lprcBounds);
#endif // SHARED_HANDLERS

#ifdef _DEBUG
    virtual void AssertValid() const;
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif

protected:

// Generated message map functions
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();

private:
    void GameOver(); 
    BOOL NewGame(); 
    int AddScoreToList(); 
    void DeleteFullRows(); 
    BOOL IsRowFull(int iRow);
    void FlashRow(int iFlashRow);
    void DeleteRow(int iDeleteRow);

#ifdef SHARED_HANDLERS
    // Helper function that sets search content for a Search Handler
    void SetSearchContent(const CString& value);
#endif // SHARED_HANDLERS
};
```

Here is the actual error log:

Error   8   error C2065: 'm_colorGrid' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\ary\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\tetris\tetris\tetrisdoc.h    36  1   Tetris

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

As you can see the  m_colorGrid is declared in the private header above the function.

Comment: Is there by any chance another error saying that ColorGrid is not defined?

Comment: @immibis or as Visual Studio like to call it for some reason `default type int assumed` when it doesn't find a type

Comment: Is that error reported by the compiler or the IntelliSense of the IDE?

Comment: Please show the compiler error **verbatim**, as displayed in the compiler output.

Comment: forward declaring `ColorGrid` is not enough, you need to include the full definition of it if you want to store it by value as a data-member. The compiler needs to know how large it is.

Comment: My compiler stops dead when it finds that weird varadic argument-like thing sitting near the end of the example. [mcve] please?

Comment: Here is the verbatim error from compiler "Error 8 error C2065: 'm_colorGrid' : undeclared identifier c:\users\ary\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\tetris\tetris\tetrisdoc.h 36 1 Tetris
"

Comment: @AryanNaim right, and the error before that?

Comment: @IInspectable, I edit the post and added the entire header file & also screenshot of the error.

Comment: @AryanNaim if you sort the errors correctly you will see that the `missing type secifier` errors come before it. It can't find the definition for  `ColorGrid`

Comment: @PeterT, there isnt an error before it but the error after it is "Error 4 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' c:\users\ary\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\tetris\tetris\tetrisdoc.h 33 1 Tetris
"

Comment: @AryanNaim it's error number 8, there's 7 before it, you sorted it weirdly alphabetically for the error description, don't do that

Comment: @PeterT, your right I added #include "ColorGrid.h" by the way how do i sort it correctly, is that the default sort order when you right click? Thanks

Comment: @Peter, thanks for resolving previous issue, Im now getting : "Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ColorGrid::ColorGrid(void)" (??0ColorGrid@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall CTetrisDoc::CTetrisDoc(void)" (??0CTetrisDoc@@IAE@XZ) C:\Users\ary\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Tetris\Tetris\TetrisDoc.obj Tetris" Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you did not define your constructor for ColorGrid

Comment: Don't just pick a single error and post it. Post **all** errors. And don't use the *Error List*, use the actual compiler output. Besides, a [mcve] needs to be minimal. Don't just dump everything. A word of warning: If you are struggling with C++ and the compiler at that basic a level, MFC is not something you will understand, or use proficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have included .h header file of "ColorGrid" or added the proper reference.